# iOS 14 widget onAppear / didAppear event?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

Is there any technique to re-render iOS 14 widget content when I scroll to my home screen (contain my widget)?

> To clarify, this is Home screen of iOS 14 where you can place any
> widget on. It's not the today extension that appeared in the very left
> Home screen.

I haven't found any document about this technique! All I know is using `Timeline` to schedule the rendering, and `refreshWidget(widgetKindHere)`

Currently, I'm using `IntentTimelineProvider` to make updating schedule, keep my stock widget up to date frequently for `every 30 minutes`

But as I can see the TradingView's widget:
When I scrolled to my home screen contain its widget, the `last updated` info on the widget changed from `12:00pm` to `2:55pm` (current)

-> That mean they did not update their widget from `12pm` to `2:30pm`, until I scrolled to the Home screen contain the widget, a few seconds later, it get updated at `2:55pm`

How can TradingView did that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about detecting `onAppear`/`onDisappear` events. What you observe is the *smart* behaviour of Smart Stacks. Usually related with the use of `TimelineEntryRelevance`.

Every [`TimelineEntry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineentry) has a [`TimelineEntryRelevance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineentry/relevance-2oovl). The relevance is required, however, the default implementation is provided.

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    var date: Date
    var relevance: TimelineEntryRelevance?
}

let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), relevance: 0.1)
```

Why `relevance` is important? It is used by Smart Stacks to display the most *relevant* widget, i.e., the one with the most *relevant* information.

From [Welcome to Design Great Widgets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10103/):

> Another feature we've created is Smart Stacks. These let you add
> several different widgets into a single location and quickly flick
> between the different widgets inside. But what is really powerful is
> that smart stacks dynamically change and adapt to how you use them.
> **Based on your behavior and context, a smart stack will automatically
> rotate to show you the most relevant widget at a given time.** [emphasis added]

From [Add configuration and intelligence to your widgets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10194/):

> You want your widget to be surfaced when you have timely information
> relevant to the people using your app, like when you know there is a
> thunderstorm coming, but not when you're just updating the temperature
> regularly.
>
> For example, if someone frequently launches your weather app to check
> on the weather, the system can instead surface your widget with that
> information to provide quicker access to what they're looking for.
>
> The second is based on relevant information from your app. So, for
> example, if a thunderstorm is happening, your widget can inform the
> system that it has a highly relevant update, and the system will
> consider surfacing your widget to the top of the stack.

---

Useful links:

- [Welcome to Design Great Widgets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10103/)
- [Add configuration and intelligence to your widgets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10194/)
- [Widgets Code-along, part 2: Alternate timelines](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10035/)